# External script syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm testing a website in IE 8, and i get this error message:

```
Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sensor=false
```

It's added in the header like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sensor=false"></script>
```

Anyone have a clue what could be wrong?

[image: From console]

Comment: Open the error console (F12) to see what the actual error is. You should get more information that that.

Comment: Added console screenshot, that's all i got.

Comment: You're missing a `/` in the end tag

Comment: edit: nop, just bad copy paste... the / is in the tag

Comment: open the network panel and look at what's being retrieved in the request for the script. is the script document malformed or not what you're expecting in any way?

Comment: actually i get an error in chrome too. I dont know if its bc im local, but it says that this API is disabled by Google. For more info read..

Comment: @EricG: Please tell if you find anything

Comment: is this key really for the same website registered where you are suing it?

Comment: Ikky, have you tested with any other browser? Could you share results from other browsers too.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and make sure that you are authorized to use that API key on the domain you are working on (probably none since you are working locally). If your key doesn't say "Any referer allowed" you will probably have to use a different api key while you are working locally and then you can restrict the referer when you deploy to a live server.